# PrimeNG p-multiselect fails to select 30000 values

Tags: multi-select, primeng

I have loaded p-multiselect with values of 30000 in array. When I click on select all from drop-down then browser hangs/freeze.
testcase: [Please check test case at plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q14lGKQCkjYxuep8xgSh?p=preview)

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="cities1" [(ngModel)]="selectedCities1"></p-multiSelect>
```

---

```
   cities1:any =[];
   selectedCities1:any = [];

   ngOnInit() {
    for (let i=0; i<30000; i++) 
      this.cities1.push({label:'City'+i, value:'City'+i});
   }
```

Please suggest.

Thanks!

Comment: So obviously it's not a good idea to load 30000 records into your form field. The only suggestion will be to load less data - either by some logic which pre-filters the data, or by lazy loading the data on scrolling / selection.

Comment: @Gerfried: Thanks for the suggestion. I am not sure on how to handle on select all?

Comment: For "select all" you could add a checkbox. I don't think anybody wants to select 30000 records out of a select box. For all other cases I would use a filter over the select box' model.